# JQuery - prepopulate form field on 3rd party form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a Netresults form on my webpage that I need to prepopulate.  The form is inserted into the page with javascript and so I am unable to see the form fields in the source code.

I would use the below code if the form was on my page but as its not, I have no idea how to target the fields.  Can anyone help?

```
var keywords = getUrlParameter('keywords');

$('input[name=netres-keywords]').val(keywords);
```

The netresults form is inserted with this code:

```
(function() {
    var $__MAForm;
    ($__MAForm =function(){
        if(typeof($__MA)=="undefined"){
            return window.setTimeout($__MAForm,50);
        }else{
            $__MA.addMAForm("43788303-2b62-4774-ad0f-63542e3ed92a", "forms.example.com");
        }
    })();
})();
```

Comment: Can you include how the inserted form appears in HTML by doing an *Inspect Element* on the page?

Comment: could do but there are a lot of forms on a lot of pages so really want to avoid that if possible

Comment: We don't need the full HTML from every single page, but I'm not sure how you expect us to populate a form that we know nothing about.

Comment: What do you need to know about the form?  The field name I am trying to target is netres-keywords.

Comment: Is the HTML embedded into your page, or is it an iFrame?

Comment: Its not in an iframe, it is embedded where-ever the javascrpt code is added.  I can see this when I inspect element but not when I view source.

Comment: And is it actually a `<form>`?

Comment: Yes Its a bog standard form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may require the use of a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

A mutation observer will check for changes to the DOM (added elements, etc), and we can use this to fire an event. The code below will change the value of an input with name `netres-keywords` any time a new `<form>` element is added to the `<body>`.

In the example JSFiddle at the bottom of this post, I've created a button that simulates a form being added to the page. As you can see, the textbox will pre-populate.

[**EXAMPLE JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/cqc9kq2t/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var keywords = "this is a test keyword";
    var formCount = $("form").length;

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
        var newFormCount = $("form").length;
        if (newFormCount > formCount) {
            $('input[name=netres-keywords]').last().val(keywords);
        }
    });

    $("button").click(function() {
        $form = $("<form>").html("<h1>New form:</h1><input type='text' name='netres-keywords'>");
        $("body").append($form);
    });
    
    var observerConfig = {
        attributes: true, 
        childList: true, 
        characterData: true 
    };
    
    var targetNode = document.body;
    observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig);
});
```

```css
form {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
    SIMULATE ADDING FORM
</button>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try

Comment: @LeeTee I notice you've added a bounty to your question. Is there any reason the answer I've provided *won't* work for you?

Comment: Hi, So sorry I just havent had chance to test the code yet!  I will give you the bounty anyway.

Comment: That's not a problem! I wasn't upset, just genuinely curious. No need to apply the bounty if the solution doesn't work!